# Rust Rodio get a list of OutputDevices

Tags: audio, rust, rodio

I'm new to the rust and I've been playing around with the [Rodio audio library](https://docs.rs/rodio/latest/rodio/).
I can play an audio file on the default audio output device like this:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use rodio::{OutputStream, Sink};
fn main() {
   let (_stream, stream_handle) = OutputStream::try_default().unwrap();
   let sink = Sink::try_new(&stream_handle).unwrap();
   let file = File::open("m.mp3").unwrap();
   let source = rodio::Decoder::new(BufReader::new(file)).unwrap();
   sink.append(source);
   loop {}
}
```

I can see that Rodio provides a method to set the audio output device for a stream [try_from_device(&Device)](https://docs.rs/rodio/0.12.0/rodio/struct.OutputStream.html#method.try_from_device) but I can't figure out how to get a list of available audio output devices and provide an arbitrary one to this function.

**---- UPDATE ----**

Based on E_net4's answer I made two simple functions to list host devices and create an `OutputStream` for a specific device and then use it anywhere I need to play an audio file on that device like this:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use rodio::*;
use rodio::cpal::traits::{HostTrait,DeviceTrait};

fn listHostDevices(){
   let host = cpal::default_host();
   let devices = host.output_devices().unwrap();
   for device in devices{ 
      let dev:rodio::Device = device.into();
      let devName:String=dev.name().unwrap();
      println!(" # Device : {}", devName);
   }
}

fn getOutputStream(device_name:&str) -> (OutputStream,OutputStreamHandle) {
   let host = cpal::default_host();
   let devices = host.output_devices().unwrap();
   let ( mut _stream, mut stream_handle) = OutputStream::try_default().unwrap();
   for device in devices{ 
      let dev:rodio::Device = device.into();
      let devName:String=dev.name().unwrap();
      if devName==device_name {
         println!("Device found: {}", devName);
         ( _stream, stream_handle) = OutputStream::try_from_device(&dev).unwrap();
      }
   }
   return (_stream,stream_handle);
}
```

And then I use the functions like this:

```
fn main() {
   listHostDevices();
   let (_stream, stream_handle) = getOutputStream("Speakers (Realtek(R) Audio)");
   let sink = Sink::try_new(&stream_handle).unwrap();
   let file = File::open("m.mp3").unwrap();
   let source = rodio::Decoder::new(BufReader::new(file)).unwrap();
   sink.append(source);
   
   loop {}
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular version of rodio you're using for this?  I can't get it to run past device.into in the listHostDevices function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rodio` uses [`cpal`](https://docs.rs/cpal/0.13.4/cpal/index.html) as the underlying audio library. This is where the concepts of *host* and *device* come from. Use the re-exported `cpal` module from `rodio` to get the system host and obtain a list of output devices.

```rust
use rodio::cpal;

let host = cpal::default_host();
let devices = host.output_devices()?;

for device in devices {
   // use device
}
```

The device values obtained will implement [`DeviceTrait`](https://docs.rs/rodio/latest/rodio/trait.DeviceTrait.html), but `rodio` works with the dynamically polymorphic type `rodio::Device` instead. Fortunately, we can easily [convert what we have via `From` or `Into`](https://docs.rs/rodio/0.12.0/rodio/struct.Device.html#impl-From%3CDevice%3E).

```
let device: rodio::Device = device.into();

// ...

stream.try_from_device(&device)?;
```

Comment: Worked for me, but only after I also added `use rodio::cpal::traits::HostTrait;` to the file.